# How to select associate Table from many to many relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first

i have a many to many relationship tables, movie and tag in code first approach in my MVC application. i want the  user to be able to select all movies that is associted with tag. for example i want to select all movies that has tag id =2. i need lambda query that will allow me do this.Any help with appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way:

```
var moviesWithTag2 = context.Movies
    .Where(m => m.Tags.Any(t => t.Id == 2))
    .ToList();
```

This will return an empty collection if there is no tag with Id=2.

Alternative (which will return `null` if there is no tag with Id=2):

```
var moviesWithTag2 = context.Tags
    .Where(t => t.Id == 2)
    .Select(t => t.Movies)
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

If you also want the `Tag` entity you could just load it including its movies:

```
var tag2 = context.Tags.Include(t => t.Movies)
    .Single(t => t.Id == 2);
```

`tag2.Movies` will contain the movies with tag Id=2.

Comment: Thank once again empty collection is fine with me.